# How to do optional reply in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'd like to discard client messages if they don't match the type I expect, but without giving a response back to the client.

Case:

If I'm specting type "A" and client sends "A" then I process "A" and a response is sent as usually.

But if the client sends "B", then just discard the message and continue listening, and, the client-side dies by timeout. I'd like to do this in order to avoid using bandwidth with trash messages and eventually ban IP's that send unexpected content.

I've tried to:

- use `stop()` but this stops processing the exchange but still responding back the original one.
- change the MEP to `inOptionalOut` but I'm not sure what to do to skip replying.

Does it make sense what I need? :S or just should I settle for replying `null` or a short text like "banned :P" ?

Comment: Can I know what kind of Camel component that you are using?

Comment: What processor so you use to process the request and decide kg the request is valid?

Comment: @WillemJiang, I've got 3 (netty4, cxf and jms-hornetq)

Comment: @MichaelBrohl... with Netty4 is easier because I use an special decoder to filter messages... but with queues and webservices I feel lost

Comment: Can you post your camel route, just an extract or a small sample? Like this it is strange what you say because we use the stop() in our routes and it never gives any answer back (dropped silently).